# Comma in algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

First let me say that this is my daughter's 7th grade algebra homework. 2nd let me say I am not looking for the answer. 3rd, I'm ashamed to be asking for help on 7th grade math. And 4th, I don't know how to enter actual math formulas in this textbox so I am resorting to coding

I do not understand the meaning of the comma in this problem:

$$-4c/ab-8c/ab,a,b\ne0$$

I believe that based on what I have read online, the `,` means `AND`. So reading that formula would be something like `4c/ab-8/ab where both a AND b are not zero`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: For future reference, using LaTeX/MathJax will make people much happier and much more likely to help. And yes, they mean that a is not 0 and b is not zero.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation used in the problem formulation is somewhat sloppy, insofar as the slash is meant to encompass both $a$ and $b$, and the two commas have different meanings:
$$-{4c\over ab}-{8c\over ab},\qquad a,b\ne0\ .$$
The first comma separates the technical assumptions from the expression that has to be simplified by the solver, whereas the second comma is shorthand for "$a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$".

Note that, e.g.,  Mathematica interprets $\>c/ab\>$ as ${\displaystyle{c\over a}}* b$.